# Escaping reverse backSlash

Tags: c#, datetime, escaping, symbols

I want to display data in this format `yyyy/mm/dd`

How I can do it? When I use

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Model.RequiredDate)
```

I get `yyyy.mm.dd`

Comment: "reverse backslash" is usually just called "forward slash" by the way.

Comment: By the way, `mm` specifier is for minutes, `MM` is for months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape it like;

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy'/'MM'/'dd}", Model.RequiredDate)
```

I strongly suspect your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is `.`, that's why [`/` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) replace itself to it.

Answer (score 1):

What about this option?

```
string DateToString(DateTime date, string seperator)
{
    return date.ToString("yyyy") + seperator + date.ToString("MM") + seperator + date.ToString("dd");
}
```

But as [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%C3%B6n%C3%BCl) said, you can also escape it like this:

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy'/'MM'/'dd}", Model.RequiredDate)
```

**EDIT:**

What about this two options?

```
string DateToString(DateTime date, string seperator, string first, string second, string third)
{
    return date.ToString(first) + seperator + date.ToString(second) + seperator + date.ToString(third);
}

string DateToString(DateTime date, string seperator, string[] format)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (string s in format)
    {
        s += (date.ToString(s) + seperator);
    }
    return result;
}
```